# creating data.table::ITime vector

Tags: r, data.table

I was surprised doing this, using the `data.table` package:

```
a = as.ITime('12:01:00')
str(a)
Class 'ITime'  int 4326
a = as.ITime(c('12:01:00','12:00:02'))
Message d'avis :
In if (!is.na(y)) return(as.ITime(y)) :
  la condition a une longueur > 1 et seul le premier élément est utilisé
str(a)
Class 'ITime'  int [1:2] 43260 43202
```

Why is this line throwing a WARNING ?

Comment: It's not written to handle vectors of length greater than 1 without a warning. This is a bug. Looking at the source code (`getAnywhere('as.ITime.character')`), it looks like the checks have to be flushed out a bit more. The page for `?ITime` does warn that it's still experimental ;)

Comment: did not know `getAnywhere` thanks for pointing it to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### This has been fixed in [data.table 1.9.2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html). From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable&pathrev=1148):

> o `as.ITime.character` no longer complains when given vector input, and will accept mixed format time entries; e.g., `c("12:00", "13:12:25")`

Here's an example:

```
as.ITime(c('12:01:00','12:00:02'))
[1] "12:01:00" "12:00:02"
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for attending to this. Made a small edit with the relevant NEWS entry.

Comment: @Arun feels good to give something back to this great package, even if it is something tiny like this